# Spring-boot application, H2 embedded database - but tables disappear when the application closes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

My **database.properties** file is:

```
datasource.driver=org.h2.Driver
datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./test_database/comixed_db;create=true
datasource.username=sa
datasource.password=

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.batch.size=20
hibernate.current.session.context.class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
hibernate.generate_statistics=false
hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=false
```

When my application starts up I see I am able to see the tables by using the h2.bat tool and peeking at the database from a web browser. However, when I shut down the application and then go back to the database with the h2.bat tool the tables are all gone!

AM I doing something incorrectly with my hibernate configuration? I am not using **create-drop** but **update** since this code is currently in flux and I'd like the tables to be adjusted as changes occur. But that doesn't seem to be the issue since it's at app **shutdown** that the tables keep going away.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How have you configured your application to consume database.properties? What version of Spring Boot are you using? Are you using Spring Boot's DevTools? A [minimal, complete, verifiable example](help/mcve) would make your question a lot easier to answer

Comment: I have a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in my application context file that loads database.properties. Then in my sessionFactory bean I set the hibernate properties as placeholder values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding the following line to **applications.properties**:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Spring-boot stopped dropping tables when the application exits.

Answer (score 2):

If you want spring boot to catch your hibernate properties you should prefix them with `spring.jpa`, so:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Otherwise, and that is the case in my opinion, spring will use the default `create-drop` options as it is dealing with an H2 in-memory database.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't change the behavior. I prefixed all of my database.properties hibernate entries with "spring.jpa" and updated my context file to use these new values. But when I ran the app, the tables were still dropped. I also changed my option from "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" to "hibernate.ddl-auto" to machine the above but that made no difference in the behavior.